# Is lasering some natural phenomenon soemwhere?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, laser

Laser is actually the simplest kind of light, from a physical point of view.

Many people think it is some rocket science simply because it is not natural but takes some human efforts to create.

So, is there any place where we can find lasering as a natural phenomenon?

Comment: how is the laser the simplest kind of light? The simplest kind is that which is easiest to make. I'd argue thermal radiation makes the simplest light. Laser light is coherent and polarized and monochromatic. That's hardly simple

Comment: Okay, from a quantum mechanics point of view.

Comment: Laser light comes in different forms. What aspect of it are you refering to? Monochromaticity? polarization? coherence? collimation? To my knowledge, the last two have no equivalent in nature.

Comment: @fffred collimation can have a natural source. It is very unlikely, but it's not impossible

Comment: @Jimdalf, even for visible light? Do you have an example?

Comment: @fffred A observed example? None come to mind. But the polar radiation jets of a quasar could be more or less collimated by fortunately placed gravitational objects, and the wavelength of the beam could be brought into the visible range by cosmological redshift. It's unlikely but possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only natural lasers I know of are astrophysical. For example a natural infrared laser in the vicinity of the star [MWC 349](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MWC_349) was [discovered in 1995](http://www.nasa.gov/home/hqnews/1995/95-148.txt). If MASERs count then a number of them are known. There's a [review in this paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2002IAUS..206..479S).

Comment: Not sure where it stands right now, but at one point there was some talk of [natural lasing in the martian atmosphere](http://laserstars.org/history/mars.html).